# protect a file from direct access while displaying the file in html

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

I have a php page that authenticates the user and then would show, in this case a video.

```
<video class="videos" preload="autoplay">
<source src="../assets/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I need to protect files like, "mp4, png, jpg, pdf, ect.." from direct access, so anyone can't just type the url location and see the file.

Could the video file be outside the web root and still be embedded on the page with some kind of fetching script?

.htaccess password protection is not a good option for me because users are already logged in to view the page. I would not like to make users submit a second username and password.

Let me know your thoughts

Comment: yup, store outside root

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow users to download files outside webroot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884677/allow-users-to-download-files-outside-webroot) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701771/how-to-serve-documents-from-outside-the-web-root-using-php

Comment: I am not looking to download the file. For display only.

Comment: ok so change the search terms, its been asked a gozodel times before. sighh.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with an exception: video files are not able to seek :( I don't have a fix for this. When using html5 video controls to pause, it returns to 0 after selecting play again. Same issue with seeking.

in the php page displayed to the user:

```
<video class="videos" preload="autoplay">
<source src="../secure.php?file=<? echo $vtitle2.'.mp4' ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

For the secure.php file that reads the file from outside the web root:

```
<?php
  //validate that the user should have access to the file here

  //Make sure it exists
  $folder = realpath('/blah/blah/blah/folderwithfiles'); 
  if(!$file = realpath($folder.'/'.$_GET['file']))
    error(404);
  if(!is_file($file))
    error(404);

  //Check for cheaters
  if(substr($file,0,strlen($folder)) !== $folder)
    error(401);

  header(sprintf("Content-type: %s;",getMimeType($file)));
  readfile($file);
  exit;

  function error ( $code = 401, $msg = null ) {
    $msgs = array(
      400 => 'Bad Request',
      401 => 'Unauthorized',
      402 => 'Payment Required',
      403 => 'Forbidden',
      404 => 'Not Found',
    );
    if(!$msg) $msg = $msgs[$code];
    header(sprintf('HTTP/1.0 %s %s',$code,$msg));
    printf('<html><head><title>%s %s</title></head><body><h1>%s</h1></body></html>',$code,$msg,$msg);
    exit;
  }

  function getMimeType ( $filename ) {
    //MIME MAP
$mime_extension_map = array(
    '3ds'           => 'image/x-3ds',
    'BLEND'         => 'application/x-blender',
    'C'             => 'text/x-c++src',
    'CSSL'          => 'text/css',
    'NSV'           => 'video/x-nsv',
    'PAR2'          => 'application/x-par2',
    'XM'            => 'audio/x-mod',
    'Z'             => 'application/x-compress',
    'a'             => 'application/x-archive',
    'abw'           => 'application/x-abiword',
    'abw.CRASHED'   => 'application/x-abiword',
    'abw.gz'        => 'application/x-abiword',
    'ac3'           => 'audio/ac3',
    'adb'           => 'text/x-adasrc',
    'ads'           => 'text/x-adasrc',
    'afm'           => 'application/x-font-afm',
    'ag'            => 'image/x-applix-graphics',
    'ai'            => 'application/illustrator',
    'aif'           => 'audio/x-aiff',
    'aifc'          => 'audio/x-aiff',
    'aiff'          => 'audio/x-aiff',
    'al'            => 'application/x-perl',
    'arj'           => 'application/x-arj',
    'as'            => 'application/x-applix-spreadsheet',
    'asc'           => 'text/plain',
    'asf'           => 'video/x-ms-asf',
    'asp'           => 'application/x-asp',
    'asx'           => 'video/x-ms-asf',
    'atom'          => 'application/atom+xml',
    'au'            => 'audio/basic',
    'avi'           => 'video/x-msvideo',
    'aw'            => 'application/x-applix-word',
    'bak'           => 'application/x-trash',
    'bcpio'         => 'application/x-bcpio',
    'bdf'           => 'application/x-font-bdf',
    'bib'           => 'text/x-bibtex',
    'bin'           => 'application/octet-stream',
    'blend'         => 'application/x-blender',
    'blender'       => 'application/x-blender',
    'bmp'           => 'image/bmp',
    'bz'            => 'application/x-bzip',
    'bz2'           => 'application/x-bzip',
    'c'             => 'text/x-csrc',
    'c++'           => 'text/x-c++src',
    'cc'            => 'text/x-c++src',
    'cdf'           => 'application/x-netcdf',
    'cdr'           => 'application/vnd.corel-draw',
    'cer'           => 'application/x-x509-ca-cert',
    'cert'          => 'application/x-x509-ca-cert',
    'cgi'           => 'application/x-cgi',
    'cgm'           => 'image/cgm',
    'chm'           => 'application/x-chm',
    'chrt'          => 'application/x-kchart',
    'class'         => 'application/x-java',
    'cls'           => 'text/x-tex',
    'cpio'          => 'application/x-cpio',
    'cpio.gz'       => 'application/x-cpio-compressed',
    'cpp'           => 'text/x-c++src',
    'cpt'           => 'application/mac-compactpro',
    'crt'           => 'application/x-x509-ca-cert',
    'cs'            => 'text/x-csharp',
    'csh'           => 'application/x-csh',
    'css'           => 'text/css',
    'csv'           => 'text/x-comma-separated-values',
    'cur'           => 'image/x-win-bitmap',
    'cxx'           => 'text/x-c++src',
    'd'             => 'text/x-dsrc',
    'dat'           => 'video/mpeg',
    'dbf'           => 'application/x-dbase',
    'dc'            => 'application/x-dc-rom',
    'dcl'           => 'text/x-dcl',
    'dcm'           => 'application/dicom',
    'dcr'           => 'application/x-director',
    'deb'           => 'application/x-deb',
    'der'           => 'application/x-x509-ca-cert',
    'desktop'       => 'application/x-desktop',
    'dia'           => 'application/x-dia-diagram',
    'diff'          => 'text/x-patch',
    'dir'           => 'application/x-director',
    'djv'           => 'image/vnd.djvu',
    'djvu'          => 'image/vnd.djvu',
    'dll'           => 'application/octet-stream',
    'dmg'           => 'application/octet-stream',
    'dms'           => 'application/octet-stream',
    'doc'           => 'application/msword',
    'dsl'           => 'text/x-dsl',
    'dtd'           => 'text/x-dtd',
    'dvi'           => 'application/x-dvi',
    'dwg'           => 'image/vnd.dwg',
    'dxf'           => 'image/vnd.dxf',
    'dxr'           => 'application/x-director',
    'egon'          => 'application/x-egon',
    'el'            => 'text/x-emacs-lisp',
    'eps'           => 'image/x-eps',
    'epsf'          => 'image/x-eps',
    'epsi'          => 'image/x-eps',
    'etheme'        => 'application/x-e-theme',
    'etx'           => 'text/x-setext',
    'exe'           => 'application/x-ms-dos-executable',
    'ez'            => 'application/andrew-inset',
    'f'             => 'text/x-fortran',
    'fig'           => 'image/x-xfig',
    'fits'          => 'image/x-fits',
    'flac'          => 'audio/x-flac',
    'flc'           => 'video/x-flic',
    'fli'           => 'video/x-flic',
    'flw'           => 'application/x-kivio',
    'fo'            => 'text/x-xslfo',
    'g3'            => 'image/fax-g3',
    'gb'            => 'application/x-gameboy-rom',
    'gcrd'          => 'text/directory',
    'gen'           => 'application/x-genesis-rom',
    'gg'            => 'application/x-sms-rom',
    'gif'           => 'image/gif',
    'glade'         => 'application/x-glade',
    'gmo'           => 'application/x-gettext-translation',
    'gnc'           => 'application/x-gnucash',
    'gnucash'       => 'application/x-gnucash',
    'gnumeric'      => 'application/x-gnumeric',
    'gra'           => 'application/x-graphite',
    'gram'          => 'application/srgs',
    'grxml'         => 'application/srgs+xml',
    'gsf'           => 'application/x-font-type1',
    'gsm'           => 'audio/x-gsm',
    'gtar'          => 'application/x-gtar',
    'gz'            => 'application/x-gzip',
    'h'             => 'text/x-chdr',
    'h++'           => 'text/x-chdr',
    'hdf'           => 'application/x-hdf',
    'hh'            => 'text/x-c++hdr',
    'hp'            => 'text/x-chdr',
    'hpgl'          => 'application/vnd.hp-hpgl',
    'hqx'           => 'application/mac-binhex40',
    'hs'            => 'text/x-haskell',
    'htm'           => 'text/html',
    'html'          => 'text/html',
    'icb'           => 'image/x-icb',
    'ice'           => 'x-conference/x-cooltalk',
    'ico'           => 'image/x-ico',
    'ics'           => 'text/calendar',
    'idl'           => 'text/x-idl',
    'ief'           => 'image/ief',
    'ifb'           => 'text/calendar',
    'iff'           => 'image/x-iff',
    'iges'          => 'model/iges',
    'igs'           => 'model/iges',
    'ilbm'          => 'image/x-ilbm',
    'iso'           => 'application/x-cd-image',
    'it'            => 'audio/x-it',
    'jar'           => 'application/x-jar',
    'java'          => 'text/x-java',
    'jng'           => 'image/x-jng',
    'jnlp'          => 'application/x-java-jnlp-file',
    'jp2'           => 'image/jpeg2000',
    'jpg'           => 'image/jpeg',
    'jpe'           => 'image/jpeg',
    'jpeg'          => 'image/jpeg',
    'jpr'           => 'application/x-jbuilder-project',
    'jpx'           => 'application/x-jbuilder-project',
    'js'            => 'application/x-javascript',
    'kar'           => 'audio/midi',
    'karbon'        => 'application/x-karbon',
    'kdelnk'        => 'application/x-desktop',
    'kfo'           => 'application/x-kformula',
    'kil'           => 'application/x-killustrator',
    'kon'           => 'application/x-kontour',
    'kpm'           => 'application/x-kpovmodeler',
    'kpr'           => 'application/x-kpresenter',
    'kpt'           => 'application/x-kpresenter',
    'kra'           => 'application/x-krita',
    'ksp'           => 'application/x-kspread',
    'kud'           => 'application/x-kugar',
    'kwd'           => 'application/x-kword',
    'kwt'           => 'application/x-kword',
    'la'            => 'application/x-shared-library-la',
    'latex'         => 'application/x-latex',
    'lha'           => 'application/x-lha',
    'lhs'           => 'text/x-literate-haskell',
    'lhz'           => 'application/x-lhz',
    'log'           => 'text/x-log',
    'ltx'           => 'text/x-tex',
    'lwo'           => 'image/x-lwo',
    'lwob'          => 'image/x-lwo',
    'lws'           => 'image/x-lws',
    'lyx'           => 'application/x-lyx',
    'lzh'           => 'application/x-lha',
    'lzo'           => 'application/x-lzop',
    'm'             => 'text/x-objcsrc',
    'm15'           => 'audio/x-mod',
    'm3u'           => 'audio/x-mpegurl',
    'm4a'           => 'audio/x-m4a',
    'm4u'           => 'video/vnd.mpegurl',
    'man'           => 'application/x-troff-man',
    'mathml'        => 'application/mathml+xml',
    'md'            => 'application/x-genesis-rom',
    'me'            => 'text/x-troff-me',
    'mesh'          => 'model/mesh',
    'mgp'           => 'application/x-magicpoint',
    'mid'           => 'audio/midi',
    'midi'          => 'audio/midi',
    'mif'           => 'application/x-mif',
    'mkv'           => 'application/x-matroska',
    'mm'            => 'text/x-troff-mm',
    'mml'           => 'text/mathml',
    'mng'           => 'video/x-mng',
    'moc'           => 'text/x-moc',
    'mod'           => 'audio/x-mod',
    'moov'          => 'video/quicktime',
    'mov'           => 'video/quicktime',
    'movie'         => 'video/x-sgi-movie',
    'mp2'           => 'video/mpeg',
    'mp3'           => 'audio/mpeg',
    'mpe'           => 'video/mpeg',
    'mpeg'          => 'video/mpeg',
    'mpg'           => 'video/mpeg',
    'mpga'          => 'audio/mpeg',
    'ms'            => 'text/x-troff-ms',
    'msh'           => 'model/mesh',
    'msod'          => 'image/x-msod',
    'msx'           => 'application/x-msx-rom',
    'mtm'           => 'audio/x-mod',
    'mxu'           => 'video/vnd.mpegurl',
    'n64'           => 'application/x-n64-rom',
    'nb'            => 'application/mathematica',
    'nc'            => 'application/x-netcdf',
    'nes'           => 'application/x-nes-rom',
    'nsv'           => 'video/x-nsv',
    'o'             => 'application/x-object',
    'obj'           => 'application/x-tgif',
    'oda'           => 'application/oda',
    'odb'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database',
    'odc'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart',
    'odf'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula',
    'odg'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics',
    'odi'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image',
    'odm'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master',
    'odp'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation',
    'ods'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
    'odt'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
    'ogg'           => 'application/ogg',
    'old'           => 'application/x-trash',
    'oleo'          => 'application/x-oleo',
    'oot'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
    'otg'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template',
    'oth'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web',
    'otp'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template',
    'ots'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template',
    'ott'           => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template',
    'p'             => 'text/x-pascal',
    'p12'           => 'application/x-pkcs12',
    'p7s'           => 'application/pkcs7-signature',
    'par2'          => 'application/x-par2',
    'pas'           => 'text/x-pascal',
    'patch'         => 'text/x-patch',
    'pbm'           => 'image/x-portable-bitmap',
    'pcd'           => 'image/x-photo-cd',
    'pcf'           => 'application/x-font-pcf',
    'pcf.Z'         => 'application/x-font-type1',
    'pcl'           => 'application/vnd.hp-pcl',
    'pdb'           => 'application/vnd.palm',
    'pdf'           => 'application/pdf',
    'pem'           => 'application/x-x509-ca-cert',
    'perl'          => 'application/x-perl',
    'pfa'           => 'application/x-font-type1',
    'pfb'           => 'application/x-font-type1',
    'pfx'           => 'application/x-pkcs12',
    'pgm'           => 'image/x-portable-graymap',
    'pgn'           => 'application/x-chess-pgn',
    'pgp'           => 'application/pgp',
    'php'           => 'application/x-php',
    'php3'          => 'application/x-php',
    'php4'          => 'application/x-php',
    'pict'          => 'image/x-pict',
    'pict1'         => 'image/x-pict',
    'pict2'         => 'image/x-pict',
    'pl'            => 'application/x-perl',
    'pls'           => 'audio/x-scpls',
    'pm'            => 'application/x-perl',
    'png'           => 'image/png',
    'pnm'           => 'image/x-portable-anymap',
    'po'            => 'text/x-gettext-translation',
    'pot'           => 'text/x-gettext-translation-template',
    'ppm'           => 'image/x-portable-pixmap',
    'pps'           => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
    'ppt'           => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
    'ppz'           => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
    'ps'            => 'application/postscript',
    'ps.gz'         => 'application/x-gzpostscript',
    'psd'           => 'image/x-psd',
    'psf'           => 'application/x-font-linux-psf',
    'psid'          => 'audio/prs.sid',
    'pw'            => 'application/x-pw',
    'py'            => 'text/x-python',
    'pyc'           => 'application/x-python-bytecode',
    'pyo'           => 'application/x-python-bytecode',
    'qif'           => 'application/x-qw',
    'qt'            => 'video/quicktime',
    'qtvr'          => 'video/quicktime',
    'ra'            => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
    'ram'           => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
    'rar'           => 'application/x-rar',
    'ras'           => 'image/x-cmu-raster',
    'rdf'           => 'text/rdf',
    'rej'           => 'application/x-reject',
    'rgb'           => 'image/x-rgb',
    'rle'           => 'image/rle',
    'rm'            => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
    'roff'          => 'application/x-troff',
    'rpm'           => 'application/x-rpm',
    'rss'           => 'text/rss',
    'rtf'           => 'application/rtf',
    'rtx'           => 'text/richtext',
    's3m'           => 'audio/x-s3m',
    'sam'           => 'application/x-amipro',
    'scm'           => 'text/x-scheme',
    'sda'           => 'application/vnd.stardivision.draw',
    'sdc'           => 'application/vnd.stardivision.calc',
    'sdd'           => 'application/vnd.stardivision.impress',
    'sdp'           => 'application/vnd.stardivision.impress',
    'sds'           => 'application/vnd.stardivision.chart',
    'sdw'           => 'application/vnd.stardivision.writer',
    'sgi'           => 'image/x-sgi',
    'sgl'           => 'application/vnd.stardivision.writer',
    'sgm'           => 'text/sgml',
    'sgml'          => 'text/sgml',
    'sh'            => 'application/x-shellscript',
    'shar'          => 'application/x-shar',
    'shtml'         => 'text/html',
    'siag'          => 'application/x-siag',
    'sid'           => 'audio/prs.sid',
    'sik'           => 'application/x-trash',
    'silo'          => 'model/mesh',
    'sit'           => 'application/stuffit',
    'skd'           => 'application/x-koan',
    'skm'           => 'application/x-koan',
    'skp'           => 'application/x-koan',
    'skt'           => 'application/x-koan',
    'slk'           => 'text/spreadsheet',
    'smd'           => 'application/vnd.stardivision.mail',
    'smf'           => 'application/vnd.stardivision.math',
    'smi'           => 'application/smil',
    'smil'          => 'application/smil',
    'sml'           => 'application/smil',
    'sms'           => 'application/x-sms-rom',
    'snd'           => 'audio/basic',
    'so'            => 'application/x-sharedlib',
    'spd'           => 'application/x-font-speedo',
    'spl'           => 'application/x-futuresplash',
    'sql'           => 'text/x-sql',
    'src'           => 'application/x-wais-source',
    'stc'           => 'application/vnd.sun.xml.calc.template',
    'std'           => 'application/vnd.sun.xml.draw.template',
    'sti'           => 'application/vnd.sun.xml.impress.template',
    'stm'           => 'audio/x-stm',
    'stw'           => 'application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.template',
    'sty'           => 'text/x-tex',
    'sun'           => 'image/x-sun-raster',
    'sv4cpio'       => 'application/x-sv4cpio',
    'sv4crc'        => 'application/x-sv4crc',
    'svg'           => 'image/svg+xml',
    'swf'           => 'application/x-shockwave-flash',
    'sxc'           => 'application/vnd.sun.xml.calc',
    'sxd'           => 'application/vnd.sun.xml.draw',
    'sxg'           => 'application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.global',
    'sxi'           => 'application/vnd.sun.xml.impress',
    'sxm'           => 'application/vnd.sun.xml.math',
    'sxw'           => 'application/vnd.sun.xml.writer',
    'sylk'          => 'text/spreadsheet',
    't'             => 'application/x-troff',
    'tar'           => 'application/x-tar',
    'tar.Z'         => 'application/x-tarz',
    'tar.bz'        => 'application/x-bzip-compressed-tar',
    'tar.bz2'       => 'application/x-bzip-compressed-tar',
    'tar.gz'        => 'application/x-compressed-tar',
    'tar.lzo'       => 'application/x-tzo',
    'tcl'           => 'text/x-tcl',
    'tex'           => 'text/x-tex',
    'texi'          => 'text/x-texinfo',
    'texinfo'       => 'text/x-texinfo',
    'tga'           => 'image/x-tga',
    'tgz'           => 'application/x-compressed-tar',
    'theme'         => 'application/x-theme',
    'tif'           => 'image/tiff',
    'tiff'          => 'image/tiff',
    'tk'            => 'text/x-tcl',
    'torrent'       => 'application/x-bittorrent',
    'tr'            => 'application/x-troff',
    'ts'            => 'application/x-linguist',
    'tsv'           => 'text/tab-separated-values',
    'ttf'           => 'application/x-font-ttf',
    'txt'           => 'text/plain',
    'tzo'           => 'application/x-tzo',
    'ui'            => 'application/x-designer',
    'uil'           => 'text/x-uil',
    'ult'           => 'audio/x-mod',
    'uni'           => 'audio/x-mod',
    'uri'           => 'text/x-uri',
    'url'           => 'text/x-uri',
    'ustar'         => 'application/x-ustar',
    'vcd'           => 'application/x-cdlink',
    'vcf'           => 'text/directory',
    'vcs'           => 'text/calendar',
    'vct'           => 'text/directory',
    'vfb'           => 'text/calendar',
    'vob'           => 'video/mpeg',
    'voc'           => 'audio/x-voc',
    'vor'           => 'application/vnd.stardivision.writer',
    'vrml'          => 'model/vrml',
    'vsd'           => 'application/vnd.visio',
    'vxml'          => 'application/voicexml+xml',
    'wav'           => 'audio/x-wav',
    'wax'           => 'audio/x-ms-wax',
    'wb1'           => 'application/x-quattropro',
    'wb2'           => 'application/x-quattropro',
    'wb3'           => 'application/x-quattropro',
    'wbmp'          => 'image/vnd.wap.wbmp',
    'wbxml'         => 'application/vnd.wap.wbxml',
    'wk1'           => 'application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3',
    'wk3'           => 'application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3',
    'wk4'           => 'application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3',
    'wks'           => 'application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3',
    'wm'            => 'video/x-ms-wm',
    'wma'           => 'audio/x-ms-wma',
    'wmd'           => 'application/x-ms-wmd',
    'wmf'           => 'image/x-wmf',
    'wml'           => 'text/vnd.wap.wml',
    'wmlc'          => 'application/vnd.wap.wmlc',
    'wmls'          => 'text/vnd.wap.wmlscript',
    'wmlsc'         => 'application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc',
    'wmv'           => 'video/x-ms-wmv',
    'wmx'           => 'video/x-ms-wmx',
    'wmz'           => 'application/x-ms-wmz',
    'wpd'           => 'application/vnd.wordperfect',
    'wpg'           => 'application/x-wpg',
    'wri'           => 'application/x-mswrite',
    'wrl'           => 'model/vrml',
    'wvx'           => 'video/x-ms-wvx',
    'xac'           => 'application/x-gnucash',
    'xbel'          => 'application/x-xbel',
    'xbm'           => 'image/x-xbitmap',
    'xcf'           => 'image/x-xcf',
    'xcf.bz2'       => 'image/x-compressed-xcf',
    'xcf.gz'        => 'image/x-compressed-xcf',
    'xht'           => 'application/xhtml+xml',
    'xhtml'         => 'application/xhtml+xml',
    'xi'            => 'audio/x-xi',
    'xla'           => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xlc'           => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xld'           => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xll'           => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xlm'           => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xls'           => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xlt'           => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xlw'           => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xm'            => 'audio/x-xm',
    'xmi'           => 'text/x-xmi',
    'xml'           => 'text/xml',
    'xpm'           => 'image/x-xpixmap',
    'xsl'           => 'text/x-xslt',
    'xslfo'         => 'text/x-xslfo',
    'xslt'          => 'text/x-xslt',
    'xul'           => 'application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml',
    'xwd'           => 'image/x-xwindowdump',
    'xyz'           => 'chemical/x-xyz',
    'zabw'          => 'application/x-abiword',
    'zip'           => 'application/zip',
    'zoo'           => 'application/x-zoo',
    '123'           => 'application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3',
    '669'           => 'audio/x-mod'
);
    //Get Extension
    $ext = strtolower(substr($filename,strrpos($filename,'.') + 1));
    if(empty($ext))
      return 'application/octet-stream';
    elseif(isset($mime_extension_map[$ext]))
      return $mime_extension_map[$ext];
    return 'x-extension/' . $ext;
  }
?>
```