# how to open any php file from localhost?

Tags: php, apache, localhost

Is there a way to run any php file from localhost ?

eg: I want to run files like `file:///C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/myfile.php` in `http://localhost/myfile.php` ,without copying the file to htdocs. basically I need to run all the .php files from apache.

is this possible ?
I just need to simply open .php files from localhost (by double clicking) , I'm using a windows system.

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7701949/1426539

Comment: What do you mean by open?

Answer (score 1):

You could edit your document root in your apache configuration.

Or create a symlink to point to your preferred document root (on *nix):

```
$ sudo ln -s /path/to/your/project/pub /var/www
```

Assuming `/var/www` is your current document root.  You'll need to move the original document root before creating the symlink.

```
$ sudo mv /var/www /var/www.bak
```

Comment: I just need to simply open .php files from localhost(by double clicking) , I'm using a windows system.